# Rail/subway itinerary website for the UK?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am planning an itinerary in the UK, and I am surprised Google Itinerary just proposes car or walk, no train.

Is there a website for finding the best train itinerary in the UK?
It must take into account most rail companies and all subway/tube/underground/overground/metro varieties.

Comment: Google Maps has added mass transit in the last year or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Mikes answer, you can also use:

- [thetrainline.com](https://thetrainline.com) - Provides information for National Rail tickets and train times.  It usually displays the cheapest ticket price available and also displays other specials offers on attractions, hotels etc
- [TFL Journey Planner](http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk) - Provides a Journey Planner for use on the Tube network in London. If you are travelling around in London I would suggest you purchase an [Oyster](http://oyster.tfl.gov.uk)* card as it is significantly cheaper than buying tickets on the day.

<sub>*Oyster cards cannot be used on National Rail - there are only available for use on the London Tube Network.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, TFL is what I needed! It allows finding what the fastest way to go from a particular place in London to another city like Cambridge, even including bus!

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.nationalrail.co.uk, which should have most of what you need.

Comment: Definitely the best webapp for this.

Comment: It does not know underground stations, for instance Stockwell or Camden Town. I need something like Google Maps does for Japan: everything from local underground stations to major lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/) . It can do door-to-door directions including trains, buses and flights. Their coverage includes National Rail.